# Right way to use external non PSR-0 libraries on Symfony2 project

Tags: php, symfony, autoload, autoloader, symfony-2.4

I'm working on a application that will connect to Intuit Quickbooks API trough theirs REST PHP SDK. In basic PHP I have things working without problem since I load files as follow:

```
require_once('../api/config.php');  // Default V3 PHP SDK (v2.0.1) from IPP
require_once(PATH_SDK_ROOT . 'Core/ServiceContext.php');
require_once(PATH_SDK_ROOT . 'DataService/DataService.php');
require_once(PATH_SDK_ROOT . 'PlatformService/PlatformService.php');
require_once(PATH_SDK_ROOT . 'Utility/Configuration/ConfigurationManager.php');
```

Now I need to use the libraries in Symfony2 controller from a Bundle and this is where my doubt comes from, how I can achieve this easily? I read a lot of docs [link1](http://kiwwito.com/add-third-party-libraries-to-symfony-2/), [Symfony Class Loader Component](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/class_loader/map_class_loader.html) and some others but even is not clear to me at all. For now I have created this structure in my `/vendor` folder as image shows:

[image: vendor structure]

The `config.php` file that yours can see there have this code:

```
/**
 * This file allows custom configuration of paths for XSD2PHP dependencies and
 * POPO classes.  Rarely necessary, but possible.
 *
 * @author Intuit Partner Platform Team
 * @version 1.0
 */

// Determine parent path for SDK
$sdkDir = __DIR__ . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR;

if (!defined('PATH_SDK_ROOT'))
    define('PATH_SDK_ROOT', $sdkDir);

// Specify POPO class path; typically a direct child of the SDK path
if (!defined('POPO_CLASS_PATH'))
    define('POPO_CLASS_PATH', $sdkDir . 'Data');

// Include XSD2PHP dependencies for marshalling and unmarshalling
use com\mikebevz\xsd2php;
require_once(PATH_SDK_ROOT . 'Dependencies/XSD2PHP/src/com/mikebevz/xsd2php/Php2Xml.php');
require_once(PATH_SDK_ROOT . 'Dependencies/XSD2PHP/src/com/mikebevz/xsd2php/Bind.php');

// Includes all POPO classes; these are the source, dest, or both of the marshalling
set_include_path(get_include_path() . PATH_SEPARATOR . POPO_CLASS_PATH);
foreach (glob(POPO_CLASS_PATH.'/*.php') as $filename)
    require_once($filename);

// Specify the prefix pre-pended to POPO class names.  If you modify this value, you
// also need to rebuild the POPO classes, with the same prefix
if (!defined('PHP_CLASS_PREFIX'))
    define('PHP_CLASS_PREFIX',    'IPP');
```

And there is where class loading magic is, at least for QBO PHP SDK way, so:

- How I should deal with this in order to use class as Symfony2 does I mean create objects and so on?
- Since this is non PSR-0 library, will be Symfony Class Loader Component the solution?
- Could you give me some ideas or even some code to help me get this working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Symfony use Composer. So the simplest way to include your SDK is to roughly make it compatible with Composer, one way or another.

This will require a `composer.json` on the package's root. Create it.

### Simplest solution

Put a classmap instruction in your `composer.json`'s `autoload` section :

```
"autoload": {
    "classmap": ['src/'],
},
```

Composer will then recursively scan the `src/` directory when generating the autoload files. And so every class will be imported when needed, without changing the namespaces or anything.

The downside is that the library still doesn't follow PSR0, with all risk included.

### Laborious solution

PSR0-ify the library by editing each source file to add the right `namespace` and `use` instruction on top of each file. It is simple, but laborious given the number of classes in the SDK.

You can then add the `autoload` section of the package's `composer.json`, like this :

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": {
        "QBO\\": "src/"
    }
},
```

### Alternative solution

When searching for this API, I found [consolibyte/quickbooks-php](https://github.com/consolibyte/quickbooks-php) this on packagist… maybe worth a try.

Comment: Ok, I can go with step 2 since will be add `namespaces` and `use` senteces to each file on the vendor structure but for step 1 I get lost, what you mean with "define that directory as a PSR0 directory for the global namespace. That way the Symfony Class Loader should find the classes in the expected location."

Comment: Clarified my answer, you don't really need to move the files. I imagined this way of explaining more simple (but obviously isn't :P). I would use the laborious solution and make it available to the community. But I'm a bit fanatic (or dumb), since the simplest solution is… simpler/quicker/saner.

Comment: This is what I did, [here](https://github.com/paquitodev/qbx) is the public repo anyway I can't get it to work on Symfony2 but it's not autoloading problem, I tough, it's another problem and I can't find it

Comment: I don't see the `composer.json` in your repo. Without it, no auto-loading. But I admire your determination.